# Locust on github actions failing to get environment for listener

Tags: github-actions, locust

I'm running a locust test via github actions using

- https://github.com/marketplace/actions/locust-load-test

I have tried to add a listener so i can fail the step depending on the results of the test

```
class logger:
@events.quitting.add_listener
def _(environment):
    if environment.stats.total.fail_ratio > 25:
        logging.error("Test failed due to failure ratio > 25%")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    elif environment.stats.total.avg_response_time > 5:
        logging.error(
            "Test failed due to average response time ratio > 50 ms")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    else:
        environment.process_exit_code = 0
```

This works locally when i execute the load test, the logger is called and works but running the same test on github actions i get the following error.

```
Name                                                          # reqs      # fails     
Avg     Min     Max  |  Median   req/s failures/s
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
--------------------------------------------------------
POST xapi-statement                                             4375     0(0.00%)     
158     132     712  |     150   39.20    0.00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-------------------------------------------------------
Aggregated                                                      4375     0(0.00%)     
158     132     712  |     150   39.20    0.00

[2023-10-27 10:09:36,337] 39ea71187fac/INFO/locust.main: Time limit reached. Stopping 
Locust.
[2023-10-27 10:09:36,356] 39ea71187fac/INFO/locust.main: Shutting down (exit code 0), 
bye.
[2023-10-27 10:09:36,356] 39ea71187fac/INFO/locust.main: Cleaning up runner...
[2023-10-27 10:09:36,356] 39ea71187fac/INFO/locust.main: Running teardowns...
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/locust", line 8, in <module>
 sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/main.py", line 324, in main
 shutdown(code=code)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/main.py", line 302, in shutdown
  environment.events.quitting.fire(reverse=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/locust/event.py", line 33, in fire
 handler(**kwargs)
TypeError: _() missing 1 required positional argument: 'environment'
```

i am not sure why the locust environment is not being passed to the listener while on github actions.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Interesting. Which locust version are you using on GH? Maybe file an isse with the makers of the action.

Comment: That action seems to default to locust 1.0.1?! That is quite some time ago :)

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Missed that.
Thanks :-)